# DI create object only when needed

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, factory

So far my service logic looks something like this

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IDataRepositoryFactory _repositoryFactory;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public MyService (IDataRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _repositoryFactory = repositoryFactory;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public object JustDoIt(string someValue)
    {
         var repo1 = _repositoryFactory.GetDataRepository<IMyRepository1>();
         var result = repo1.GetSomething(someValue);
         if (result == null)
         {
             var repo2 = _repositoryFactory.GetDataRepository<IMyRepository2>();
             var result = repo2.GetSomething(someValue);
         }
         return result;
    }
}
```

And with this design I have a problem. My project have MVC and Web Api controllers and since I must create different containers for web api and mvc requests I can't determine which container to use. So I decided maybe should get rid of repository factory and inject repositories, but I dont want to create `IMyRepository2` instantly because I may not need it.

So maybe you have some suggestions about what should I do.

Comment: Depending on the actual service container you're using, most have some way of injecting a factory instead of the actual service. Try injecting `Func<IMyRepository2>` and see if that works, if so then you should be able to call that delegate every time you need an instance of that repository. Having said that, the construction of service objects should be a cheap thing though so unless the service implementation fills a cache from the database or something like that during construction I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I am using SimpleInjector. Could you provide some sample code how it should look?

Comment: I would imagine something like: `public MyService(Func<IMyRepository1> repositoryFactory1, Func<IMyRepository2> repositoryFactory2, IUnitOfwork unitOfWork)` though I see that you're already using a factory, is the same factory already capable of resolving both repositories? If so then what is the problem with the code you have?

Comment: Factory is not capable of distinguishing between web api and mvc requests so there is no way to determine which container to use.

Answer (score 0):

This concept is called Lazy Loading and can be achieved using the [Lazy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Instead of injecting the repository, you inject a Lazy object, which might build the interface whenever you call the Value property on the Lazy object.

You can remove the factory and inject all repositories you might need.

```
public class MyService : IMyService {
    private readonly Lazy<IRepository> _repo;

    public MyService(Lazy<IRepository> repo) {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public void Act(...) {
        _repo.Value.Save(..);
    }
}
```